# Debugging doesn't work using CLion in Catalina

Tags: debugging, clion

After the update debugging doesn't work in any project in CLion. By not working I imply that it ignores all the breakpoints which are not muted. Is it a common issue with macOS 10.15?

Comment: Issue resolved after CLion update